# Interface Python Thrift client with Go gRPC server

Tags: python, go, grpc, thrift

Is that possible to begin with? It says in the [gRPC FAQ](https://grpc.io/faq/):

> **Can I use gRPC with my favorite data format (JSON, Protobuf, Thrift, XML) ?**
>
> Yes. gRPC is designed to be extensible to support multiple content
>   types. The initial release contains support for Protobuf and with
>   external support for other content types such as FlatBuffers and
>   Thrift, at varying levels of maturity.

But I haven't found any documentation around this? Specifically I want to talk from a Python client (Thrift) to my gRPC server writtein in Go.

Comment: I would assume "*extensible*" and "*external support*" really means "*We believe you can technically theoretically do it but nobody really tried so far. there may be resources on the web, but basically you're on your own if it does not work*".  Unless you are doing simple things you will probably hit some speed bumps sooner or later. But I never tried myself so maybe I'm totally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot have a Python Thrift client communicate with a Go gRPC server.

There are two similar but related things being mixed: the RPC protocol and the message schema/IDL/format.

The RPC protocol between Thrift and gRPC is different. They are not interoperable. This is what you are requesting, and so this is why the answer is no.

The gRPC FAQ is saying that is is possible to use things other than protobuf as the message schema/IDL/format. So that would allow a Python gRPC client talking to a Go gRPC server, but using Thrift messages. [grpc-ecosystem/grift](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grift) contains some unmaintained code that allows generating gRPC stubs from Thrift IDL files, but it doesn't support Python.